# sql bulk insert c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

i want to insert 10000+ rows in my database fast (I tried with linqtosql and it took me more than 2 minutes) and after a research on the internet I found out about SQL Bulk Copy, but I am don't really understand it. Can someone give me a good example in my case?
I fill a list from a .csv file so all my data are in this

```
List<myTable> datalist = new List<myTable>();
```

and I also have a context in order to execute SQL transactions.

Comment: Check a tutorial, create a new project using new database and do the bulk copy. After understanding the tutorial start implementing it in your case.

Comment: Really helpful advice lol

Answer (score 1):

To use `SqlBulkCopy` you need either `DataTable` or an `IDataReader`. If you have a `List<T>`, that can still work - via tools like [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) which makes an `IDataReader` from a sequence of objects, for example:

```
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) 
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "Id", "Name", "Description")) 
{ 
  bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"; 
  bcp.WriteToServer(reader); 
}
```

(obviously use `datalist` in place of `data`; the strings afterwards are the members to map into columns - you could use `nameof` here in recent versions of C#, i.e. `nameof(myTable.Id)` in place of `"Id"`)

If you want to work directly from the CSV without the `List<T>` in the middle, [CsvReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/) would be more appropriate.

Comment: "The name 'ObjectReader' does not exist in current context"

Comment: @L.Achilles yeah, that's an example of using FastMember - to use that you'll need to install FastMember from nuget

Comment: Oh, unfortunately I can't download new nuget packages because I can't have any internet access with that pc.